# Validate field from an api post request

Tags: laravel

So what I want to do is send an axios request with a field and data to a Laravel controller called VerifyController.php

The function I started to write is:

```
    public function checkUsername(Request $request) {
        Validator::make($request, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        ])->validate();

        return true;
    }
```

All I want to do is send an axios request to /api/verifyusername with the field name and its corresponding data and see if it comes back as available or taken

What does the function need to actually look like? Ive NEVER done this before as I am more of a frontend only guy

Comment: technically what you have would work, on the front side you would just be checking for the type of response (success or failure) as the `validate` method will throw an Exception if validation fails which would end up returning a 422 response (failure)

Comment: @lagbox ok so thats what I thought, but it is giving me an error when I do a curl test.  I was using this "curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "bossryan"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checkusername" it gives me the error "TypeError: Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array"

Comment: the `make` method doesn't take a Request it takes the associative array of data .. you are thinking of the `validate` method of Controller, which takes a Request and array of rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function checkUsername(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ]);

    return true;
}
```

Or

```
public function checkUsername(Request $request) {
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ])->validate();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So, this is amazing - I see how what I was doing wrong. So if I get a return of 1 - then its valid and not in the database, if I get a redirect, then its in the DB, totally makes sense!!!